# Run Python Import Email Body Plain json

Tags: python, json, zapier

How do I import an Email_Body_Plain that only contains a JSON using Python zapier Action?

Answer (score 0):

This works. Can anyone make it cleaner?  Message is the Hash that had my message.

```
import json
jsonObject = json.loads(input_data['EmailMessage'])
return  json.loads(jsonObject['Message'])
```

Comment: This only works in the test.  When It active it sends an email with KeyError:'EmailMessage'

Comment: Probably `input_data` (which you control as the input) is not provided - perhaps the trigger only has data some of the time?